# Michael Hartl Chapter 3.3.1 Rails Test error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

Ive followed the tutorial word by word, and I'm using the Cloud9 platform to follow along. 
I'm supposed to run: $ rails test
I'm supposed to get: 2 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

I'm not sure if i'm running the wrong command since i'm using Cloud9, but when I run the program the pages work, meaning I shouldn't be getting any errors at all.  It's almost as if the test's never run at all.  Any ideas?

enter code he(static-pages) $ rails test
Running via Spring preloader in process 5822
Run options: --seed 31158

## Running:

...

Finished in 0.554944s, 5.4060 runs/s, 5.4060 assertions/s.
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:9:in `aggregated_results': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.10.2/lib/minitest.rb:597:in`report'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/minitest-reporters-1.1.9/lib/minitest/minitest_reporter_plugin.rb:26:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/minitest-reporters-1.1.9/lib/minitest/minitest_reporter_plugin.rb:26:in`report'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.10.2/lib/minitest.rb:687:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.10.2/lib/minitest.rb:687:in`report'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.10.2/lib/minitest.rb:141:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:73:in`run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.10.2/lib/minitest.rb:63:in `block in autorun'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in`fork'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `serve'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in`block in run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in`run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from -e:1:in`'re

Answer (score 0):

Ugg just found out this question was already answered elsewhere.
Apparently there is a bug in the Minitest Gem file.

I added the code below to the test/test_helper.rb file to resolve it.  However, i'm pretty sure there are other ways to resolve it as well.

Minitest::Reporters.use!